# Reduce does not get a result

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I try to solve the following inequation.

```
Reduce[
  (k^-n (k (-k + k^n) y + (-1 + k) x (-1 + k + y)))/((-1 + k) (x + y*n)) < 1/n && 
   x > 0 && y > 0 && n ∈ Integers &&k ∈ Integers, 
  {x, y, k, n}]
```

Unfortunately,`Reduce` does not get a result. Any suggestion on how to solve it?

Comment: Although the documentation does not explicitly mention it, `Reduce[]` is very lame when dealing with exponentials. For example, it can't do `Reduce[2 == 2^n + 2^m, {n, m}, Integers]` which should be easy. Try `FindInstance[]` instead which is more capable.

Comment: As I read this, you are trying to find a solution for 4 variables from one equation.  Is this what you want?  Do you really want an inequality for x?

Comment: Something can be done by specification of $n$ and $k$, e.g. Reduce[(n*((k^-n (k (-k + k^n) y + (-1 + k) x (-1 + k + y)))/((-1 + 
           k) (x + y*n))) < 1) /. {n -> 1, k -> 2} && x > 0 && 
   y > 0, {x, y}, Reals]

Comment: @mikado I try to find the upper bound of left expression, and I hope '1/n' it is ( it will simplify my following calculation)

Comment: I can't give you a solution for this, but I think the appropriate Mathematica operator is `ForAll`

Comment: If you are looking for an upper bound, please place that important informaion **in** the body of your question instead of a comment.

Comment: By the way, the inequality is false in general. Try `n=k=x=y=2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the answer provided by [bill-s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1783/bill-s) provides ten instances violating the original inequality,

```
FindInstance[(k^-n (k (-k + k^n) y + (-1 + k) x (-1 + k + y)))/((-1 + k) (x + y*n)) < 1/n 
    && x > 0 && y > 0 && n \[Element] Integers && k \[Element] Integers, {x, y, k, n}, 10]
```

gives ten instances satisfying the original inequality.  An example is

```
(* {x -> 5683/5, y -> 2331/10, k -> 10084, n -> 1132} *)
((k^-n (k (-k + k^n) y + (-1 + k) x (-1 + k + y)))/((-1 + k) (x + y*n)) < 1/n) /. %
(* True *)
```

It is, therefore, natural to ask what portion of random sets of `{x, y, k, n}` satisfy the inequality.  The expression,

```
Count[ParallelTable[{x = RandomReal[10^5], y = RandomReal[10^5], 
    k = RandomInteger[{-10^5, 10^5}], n = RandomInteger[{-10^5, 10^5}],
    tst = (k^-n (k (-k + k^n) y + (-1 + k) x (-1 + k + y)))/((-1 + k) (x + y*n)), 
    tst < 1/n}, 100000], False, Infinity]
```

suggests that about 70% do.  Replacing the right side of the inequality to `2/n` increases the percentage to about 82%, but further increasing the right side moderately yields no improvement.  An example of a random set for which the inequality is far from satisfied is

```
(* {99896.2, 4488.5, -40330, -43962, 7.317356679375576*10^202473, False} *)
```

Such instances arise when `k` and `n` both are large negative integers, with `k` or `n` even, and also occasionally when `k` is positive and `n` is negative and even.  Further, the left side of inequality can be arbitrarily large amount in such instances.

To assure that the inequality always is satisfied, require that both `k > 1` and `n > 0`, and increase the right side of the inequality to `2/n`.  (A tighter bound, say `1.6/n`, also works.)

Answer (score 4):

Taking a hint from Somos, you can see that your inequality is false in general. Use FindInstance with the opposite sign on the inequality:

```
FindInstance[(k^-n (k (-k + k^n) y + (-1 + k) x (-1 + k + y)))/((-1 + k) (x + y*n)) > 1/n 
    && x > 0 && y > 0 && n \[Element] Integers && k \[Element] Integers, {x, y, k, n}, 10]
```

This returns 10 cases where the original inequality, with less then 1/n, is false.